# Loading intermediate certificate into Infoblox NIOS

Tags: ssl, https, dns, ssl-certificate, infoblox

We have an SSL/TLS certificate loaded into an infoblox NIOS appliance that is one of the newer/cheaper certificates that usually require an intermediate certificate to complete verification of authenticity in modern web browsers.

The infoblox NIOS appliance server is no longer under support, and the documentation explicitly states that loading an intermediate certificate is supported. However, it does not specify how to accomplish that. Trying to load the certificate and intermediate as a bundle causes the NIOS interface to respond with an error that the certificate is invalid. Trying to load the certificates individually does not work as it only allows one certificate to be loaded for the HTTPS interface.

Anyone know how to do this using the NIOS web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Infoblox NIOS admin guide (http://dloads.infoblox.com/direct/appliance/NIOS/NIOS_AdminGuide_8.0.pdf):

> When you receive the certificate from the CA, and import it
>    to the appliance, the NIOS 
>   appliance finds the matching 
>   CSR and takes the private key associated with the CSR and 
>   associates it with the newly imported certificate. **The 
>   appliance then automatically deletes the CSR.**
>
> If the CA sends an intermediate certificate that must be 
>   installed along with the server certificate, you can upload 
>   both certificates to the appliance. The appliance supports 
>   the use of intermediate certificates to complete the chain 
>   of trust from the server certificate to a 
>   trusted root CA. This eliminates intermediate certificate security warnings that 
>   appear when you open a web browser and try to connect to an Infoblox appliance.

It's annoying, but it seems you have to make a new CSR every time, then you can upload the certificate.  I put the server certificate and the intermediate certificate in the same .pem file, and that seemed to work.

Comment: Yes this makes no sense, it doesn't allow you to import a pvt key in case you already have a cert!